# How to use _or_ condition in template strings?

Tags: javascript, html, template-strings

I'm creating a project using node.js. I'm using `yo-yo` library to create html templates.

I want to add a cover from tweet user profile_banner_url.

Like this:

```
const yo = require('yo-yo')
module.exports = function (tweet) {
  return yo`
    <div class='cover'>
      <img src='${tweet.user.profile_banner_url}' />
    </div>
  `
}
```

However, sometimes tweets don't return any *profile_banner_url*, which gives an error in browser.

I tried to add a different image from `public` directory:

```
<img src='${tweet.user.profile_banner_url} || otherimg.jpg' />
```

But it didn't work.

What is the best approache to use `or` condition in template strings?

Comment: Note that you can use template-strings in JavaScript, but not in HTML. Your code looks like HTML, but perhaps it's actually inside `.js` file or a `<script>` tag?

Comment: @ArneHugo Excatly. Using `yo-yo` library. Is a template made in js. I edited the question with this detail, Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for

```
`<div class='cover'>
  <img src='${tweet.user.profile_banner_url || 'otherimg.jpg'}' />
</div>`
```

Notice that the part inside the `${`…`}` is just a regular javascript expression.

Answer (score 1):

I guess now it's possible to use the nullish coalescing operator like

```
<img src="${some_url ?? 'publicurl.jpg'}" />
```

Or a regular ternary

```
<img src="${some_url !== undefined ? some_url : 'public.jpg'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for my case

```
`<input class="range-slider__slider" type="range" ${ ( (inputType) => {
                  if(inputType == 'temperature')
                    return 'min="-10" max="30" value="23" data-type="' + inputType +'"';
                  else if(inputType == 'light')
                    return 'min="0" max="1000" value="300" data-type="' + inputType +'"';
                  else if(inputType == 'floor')
                    return 'input(type="range" min="0" max="30" value="23" data-type="' + inputType + '"';
                  else
                    return ''
                } )(inputType)}">`
```